# What is eth_dr in ethernet ip in c++/C?

Tags: c++, c, windows, driver, mobile-broadband-api

i want to write a line of code inside a driver module to get support on Mobile broadband . This is the code :

```
   PUCHAR pCurrData;

   struct eth_hdr *pEthHeader = (struct eth_hdr*)pCurrData;
   NET_BUFFER_LIST_INFO(pNBL, NetBufferListFrameType) = (PVOID)(ULONG_PTR)pEthHeader->type;

    switch( pEthHeader->type ){

        case PP_HTONS(ETHTYPE_IP):

             NdisSetNblFlag(pNBL, 0x00000200 /*NDIS_NBL_FLAGS_IS_IPV4*/);

         break;

            }
```

so my doubt , what is   `struct eth_hdr` ? which header file i include ? so i should define this structure as my own ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching a little bit on google returns these [precise lines from a repo on GitHub](https://github.com/hzeroo/Carberp/blob/master/source%20-%20absource/pro/all%20source/bootkit/KipLib/protocol.c#L1073).

Using the GitHub search feature on the repo [returns those lines](https://github.com/hzeroo/Carberp/blob/6d449afaa5fd0d0935255d2fac7c7f6689e8486b/source%20-%20absource/pro/all%20source/bootkit/iplib/include/netif/etharp.h#L72):

```
/** Ethernet header */
struct eth_hdr {
#if ETH_PAD_SIZE
  PACK_STRUCT_FIELD(u8_t padding[ETH_PAD_SIZE]);
#endif
  PACK_STRUCT_FIELD(struct eth_addr dest);
  PACK_STRUCT_FIELD(struct eth_addr src);
  PACK_STRUCT_FIELD(u16_t type);
} PACK_STRUCT_STRUCT;
PACK_STRUCT_END
#ifdef PACK_STRUCT_USE_INCLUDES
#  include "arch/epstruct.h"
#endif
```

This seems to describe only a part of an [ethernet frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame) with MAC Dest, MAC source and Ethertype.

You should notice that this code is extracted directly from a **bootkit** (namely [Caberp](https://securityintelligence.com/carberp-source-code-sale-free-bootkit-included/)) which, among other things, inject a network driver in the kernel network driver stack. I don't think this kind of code is a good start for getting an idea on how a NDIS driver should be made.

There are enough good NDIS driver samples on the WDK to start with.

Comment: okay . i know that . But i want to add only mobile broadband support for NDIS . So this line of code is to check the Netbuffer list for the mobile broadband type . Anyway Thank u very much .